# Delete values from array which are more than one time

Tags: java, arrays

this is my task. I want to create a method which delete duplicate values from array for example {1,0,0,2,3,4}, so after should be {1,2,3,4} and so on.This is what I've created :

```
public void delete() {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1 ; j < tab.length; j++) {
                if (tab[i] == tab[j]) {
                    for (int c = j; c < tab.length-1; ++c) {
                        tab[i] = tab[i+1];
                    tab[c] = tab[c+1];
                    //tab[i] = tab[i+1];
                    tab.length--;
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work in this way what I want. if I have an array like :

```
{0,1,6,8,5,7,1,1,2,8}
```

after method it looks like that:

```
{0,6,6,8,5,7,1,2}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You cannot change the length of an `Array` once it is created. If you can, use a `List` or rework it.

Comment: I'm assuming `tab` is an array.  This shouldn't even compile.  You can't alter the length of an array.  It is final.  You can only ever create a new array of a different size and copy the contents from the original to the new one.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile, you can't decrement an array

Comment: Use SET , it will automatically handle duplicate value for you .

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. "Delete a values from array" is not very clear.  {1,0,0,2,3,4} to {1,2,3,4} means you want to trim all zeros? Please clarify

Comment: delete an duplicate values, zero is in this example a duplicate value.

Comment: I can't use Sets and any arrays method from API. I want to create algoryth-method. :)

Answer (score 0):

So as other posters mentioned, you really don't want to do what you are trying to do as resizing an array is really fighting against what an array was meant to do in the first place. I would recommend checking out some alternative data structures such as an ArrayList (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which will monitor size on its own so that you don't have to worry about space constraints.

If for some reason you do need to resize your array, you want to use the Arrays.copyOf method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to create a secondary array that is resized to your need and then populate it with the values from the first array:

```
int[] array1 = { Some Values};
int[] array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, 2 * array1*length);
array2 = array1;
```

**BUT....**

This is a really expensive and pointless practice in almost *all* cases. Rather than try to delete your unused array fields, set them to null instead. Then your data structure can stay constant (which requires very little memory) and you can work around those null fields as needed, even repopulating them when you see fit.

Comment: I need to create without ArrayList.

Comment: Fair enough... if that is the case though I would set your array to a specific size and then work within those boundries without worrying about null values. For length maintain an instance variable of your count to keep track of what you have stored in the array and for all other methods just have them ignore null.